# Create enum dynamically in a PostgreSQL database in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, enums, node-postgres

I have a service, written in Node, that calls an endpoint at start-up, receives back an array of values, and the array should then be used to create an Enum in a PostgreSQL database. The enum is later used to create a table in the same database.

The usual query looks like this:

```
DO $$
    BEGIN
        IF
            NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1 FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'tableType'
                )
        THEN
            CREATE TYPE
                tableType
            AS
                ENUM (
                    firstType, secondType
                    );
        END IF;
    END $$;
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_table(
  id,
  enumValue tableType
);
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to transform the above query and make it dynamic.

I have tried the following approaches:

1. With a single parameter

```
ENUM (
  $1
);
```

And then:

```
  ---
  const tableTypes = await axios.get('/tableTypes');

  await pgPool.query('BEGIN');
  const createEnumQuery = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './sql/createEnum.sql')).toString();
  await pgPool.query(createEnumQuery, [tableTypes .data]); // or just tableTypes.data
  await pgPool.query('COMMIT');
```

2. With multiple parameters by manually generating the SQL using a for loop

```
ENUM (
  $1, $2, $3, ...
);
```

```
  ---
  const tableTypes = await axios.get('/tableTypes');

  await pgPool.query('BEGIN');
  const createEnumQuery = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './sql/createEnum.sql')).toString();
  await pgPool.query(createEnumQuery, tableTypes .data);
  await pgPool.query('COMMIT');
```

Is there a way to do this?